# How to create a variable from another class object

Tags: java, hibernate, oop

I have two Java classes, Product and ProductReview. ProductReview has in addition to variables long id and String review a variable named Product that should contain an object from the class Product. Example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Product Reviews")
public class ProductReview implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id
@Column
private long id;

@Column
private String review;

private (stuck here, how do I type another classes object as a variable?)
```

The Product class has private variables long id, String name and List reviews (which also takes the reviews from ProductReviews class). Product class has a one-to-many association to ProductReviews and vice versa.

So my question is: What is the correct syntax for creating the third variable in the example above? The variable should be an instance of a Product-object.

Comment: Please could you add a question statement? This might be a good question but currently its unclear what you are asking.

Comment: something like `private Product product`. Honestly, you shouldn't start with JPA if you dont know the very language basics...

Answer (score 0):

You can use below Classes and Mapping

```
@Entity
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="Product_Id")
private int id;

@Column(name="Product_Name")
private String name;

@Column(name="Product_Price")
private double price;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true,mappedBy="product")
private Set<ProductReview> review = new HashSet<ProductReview>();

public Product(String name, double price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}
//Getter and Setter
}
```

and ProductReview Class

```
@Entity
public class ProductReview {

@javax.persistence.Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="Review_Id")
private int Id;

@Column(name="Review")
private String review;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="Product_Id")
private Product product;

public ProductReview(String review, Product product) {
    this.review = review;
    this.product = product;
}

public ProductReview() {

}
//Getter and Setter
}
```

[Product Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRhid.png)

[ProductReview Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02Aqi.png)